# Issues in building an application on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, api

http://www.inforbiro.com/blog-eng/free-viral-facebook-application-with-step-by-step-tutorial/

I have followed everything what the above link asked me too..
but still i am getting this error on facebook.

This webpage is not available
The webpage at https://skyfreez.com/lovecal/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Unknown error.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to your server log for more info, but I'm pretty sure this is related with Facebook asking for a secure page (https) that you don't have.

They added the SSL requirement for apps [a few months ago](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/):

> October 1: All Canvas apps must process signed_request (fb_sig will be
>   removed) and **obtain an SSL certificate** (unless you are in Sandbox
>   mode). This will ensure that users browsing Facebook over HTTPS will
>   have a great experience over a secure connection.

Comment: How do i get an SSL certificate?

Comment: You could go to places like http://www.rapidssl.com/, but I'd first check the FAQ regarding SSL on your web hosting: http://faq.1and1.com/domains/domain_admin/ssl/index.html